# Convert text to speech on mac when button pressed

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a script which will read a text file and then speak one line of the file every time I press a button on my keyboard. I am using the system accessibility voice on my Mac as the voice sounds more human than some of the python modules I tried.

So far my script runs and speaks a line but the spoken lines are not in order but rather are just lines spoken at random, whereas I would like each line to be spoken once and in order.
Also,  I would rather use another key (not alphanumeric) such as right arrow to invoke the function but not sure how to specify that in my script?

I am just learning to code so any help would be much appreciated.

I am using Python 3.9.1 on  Mac OSX 10.15.5

```
filename = ('file.txt')

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
 #   for x in lines:
 #       pass

def say():
    while True:
        try:  # used try so that if any key other than the specified key is pressed an error will not be shown
            for x in lines:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('l'):  # if key 'l' is pressed
                    subprocess.call(['say', x])
                    print('You Pressed A Key!')
                    #break  # finishing the loop
        except:
            break  # this should break loop if user presses a key other than the given key but doesn't work
say()
```

Ok I have now managed to fix the issue of reading from a file and reading each line in sequence (see clode below).

And aparantly you can just specify the key with 'up' or 'right' which works. It does output random characters to the screen so if anyone has a better way of doing this, I'd love to hear it

```
import keyboard
import subprocess

filename = ('text.txt')

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def say():
    i=0
    while i <len(lines):
        try:  # used try so that if any key other than the specified key is pressed an error will not be shown
            if keyboard.is_pressed('up'):  # if key 'up' is pressed
                subprocess.call(['say', lines[i]])
                i += 1
        except:
            break  # this should break loop if user presses a key other than the given key but doesn't work

say()
```

Comment: i think its because it keeps iterating because of `while` statement and ignores say when you dont press `l`, If you want it to read all lines when you press l,  you might want to swap `if`statement and `for` statement. Sadly I do not have a mac to try this out.

Comment: @JackSparrow thanks. I need the While statement so the scripts waits until I press the l key to speak a line. Then it waits until I press l key again before speaking the next line - is that makes sense ?

Since I am reading the file into a list I guess I just need it to iterate through the list everytime the button is pressed but not sure hot to do it

Comment: do you want one specific line to be read out or do you want all lines read in the right order?

Comment: also do you want to press a button once and have all lines read at once or do you want a keystroke per line?

Comment: @JackSparrow I would like all lines to be read out in the right order using a key stroke per line. My second code example now seems to works but is probably not the best way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import keyboard
import subprocess

CURRENT_LINE = 0 #records line to be read out, first line is 0.

def ttsLine(line): #TTS function, uses macs say as per you requested. 
    try:
        k = subprocess.check_output(["say",line.strip()]) #using subprocess, line.strip() to clean each line.
        return True   #returns true so we know if say command was successful
    except:
        return False #returns false if exceptions occured.

filename = ('text.txt') #text file with lines to be read.

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines() #saving lines to array.

while True:
    keyboard.wait("up") #Waits until up key is pressed.

    if not ttsLine(lines[CURRENT_LINE]): #if ttsLine returned false, something went wrong and script halts.
        print("Something went wrong while reading out", lines[CURRENT_LINE])
        break

    CURRENT_LINE += 1 #else we update line to next one

    if CURRENT_LINE == len(lines): #if all lines have been read, script ends.
        break
```

Comment: Tested and works perfectly. I think this catches any possible errors much better - many thanks.